# Cannot get array after unserialize()

Tags: php, arrays

I am not getting my orignal array after using unserialize(). 
I am retrieving array from database and want to display it. 
I have 2 arrays, created them from checkbox input, then I serialize() them and stored it in database.

Create.php

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>Aadhar</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="original[]" value="Aadhar"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="xerox[]" value="Aadhar"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Pan Card</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="original[]" value="Pan Card"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="xerox[]" value="Pan Card"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="original[]" value="Address"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="xerox[]" value="Address"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Light Bill</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="original[]" value="Light Bill"/></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="xerox[]" value="Light Bill"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Create2.php(this page is just like confirmation page..before user submit to the database.)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$original_list = $_POST['original'];
$xerox_list = $_POST['xerox'];
?>

<form action="create2.php" method="POST">
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" readonly="readonly" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Mobile</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Email</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php $original_list ?>"  />
  <input type="hidden" name="xerox_list" value="<?php $xerox_list ?>" />
  <td>Documents Selected</td>
  <td>
    <?php
    echo "<b>ORIGINAL</b><br />";
    foreach($original_list as $value)
    {
      echo $value."<br />";
    }
    ?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php
    echo "<b>XEROX</b><br />";
    foreach($xerox_list as $value)
    {
      echo $value."<br />";
    }
    ?>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Create2.php (insert in database)

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$company = $_POST['company'];

$original = serialize($_POST['original_list']);
$xerox = serialize($_POST['xerox_list']);


echo $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,mobile,email,company,original,xerox)
VALUES ('$name','$mobile','$email','$company','$original','$xerox')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

So when I try to unserialize, and display the array using foreach, this is what I get:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Code:

```
  $original = unserialize($rows['original']);
  foreach($original as $value)
  {
    echo $value."<br />";
  }
```

Comment: How did you serialize value. in your code there is no value after serialize

Comment: Before querying it to the database, this is what i did:
$original = serialize($_POST['original_list']);

Comment: Yes there are suppose to be values after serialization but I am not getting.

Comment: post complete php code

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php $original_list ?>"  />

I am passing the array like this before i serialize it, I think this line is not working.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php $original_list ?>" />` you didn't write 'echo' in php `<input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php echo $original_list; ?>" />`

Comment: I can't echo it, its an array. I need to find out  some other way to pass the array. any idea how can i do that?

Comment: try this in create2.php `$original_list = $_POST['original[]'];
$xerox_list = $_POST['xerox[]'];`

Comment: Actually, I found out a way, instead of serializing later, i did it here, so i can pass it through hidden input.
<input type="hidden" name="original_list" value="<?php echo serialize($original_list); ?>"  />

Comment: Now I am getting the serialized format in database: **a:2:{i:0;s:6:** i
But still the problem is there, i cannot unserialize and not getting the original array

Comment: Hello, I think the problem is with the SQL statement. Its trimming where it finds " in the string. How can i deal with that?